# GES/GOES Application ID or Date of Birth is incorrect, when applying for Background verification - Global Entry

Tags: indian-citizens, vfs-global, global-entry, trusted-traveler

I have completed my application on CBP website. I am trying to login to Passport seva website and while registering for GEP verification I keep getting this error message,

> Entered GES/GOES Application ID or Date of Birth is incorrect or not available with Passport Seva System. Please note it may take up to one day for your application to reflect in Passport Seva System from date of applying in Global Online Enrollment System (GOES).

I have double checked the inputs and they seem to match with the application. It’s been a week since I completed my application on CBP website. Does anyone know how long does it usually take for the Passport seva website to update? Also, how do we get GES ID, is that the same application ID on CBP website?

Answer (score 2):

I filled out my application about a week ago and I see the same error message. From reading through other posts here looks like it might take about 10 days or so to update. Please post an update here when yours does.